# How to zoom or blur video poster in html5?

Tags: html, video, html5-video, poster

I'm trying to create a video gallery like this web site:
[www.pmc.tv](http://www.pmc.tv)
My webpage is:
 [www.mohsend.com/music-videos](http://www.mohsend.com/music-videos)

But I can't give my poster video an effect, e.g. zoom poster when the mouse is over or blur it.

This is my sample video post:

```html
<table>

<td>

<video controls="controls" width="540" height="306" preload="none" poster="http://mohsend.com/images/poster/adib.jpg">
<source src="example.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<h6 class="highlightColor">ADIB TAOOSI</h6><h6>''Xoshawistm''<br>director: Mohsen Dadsetan<br>COMING SOON...</h6>
</td>


<td>

<video controls="controls" width="540" height="306" preload="none" poster="http://mohsend.com/images/poster/sohafarhad.jpg">
<source src="example.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<h6 class="highlightColor">SOHA & SARO FT FARHAD MANSORI</h6><h6>''Era Kurdistana''<br>director: Mohsen Dadsetan<br>2015</h6>

</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not apply effect on video. In your reference website they have applied the effect on its reference image. This is the example from that website.

```
<img width="480"
     height="295"
     src="http://pmc.tv/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Saed-Deylami-Sakhte.mp41-480x295.jpg"
     class="attachment-folio-thumb2 wp-post-image" alt="Saed Deylami - Sakhte.mp4">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much related to the poster image. They are using an image which a CSS rule is applied to using a transition on hover.

The image can be wrapped inside a div with overflow set to hidden. The main image (or video element if you prefer) has a transform applied to it. When hovered a different transform is applied with a transition parameter to animate between them.

## Example

```css
.wrapper {
  width:480px;
  height:295px;
  overflow:hidden
  }
.demo {
  transform:rotate(0deg) scale(1);
  transition: 0.5s transform;
  }
.demo:hover {
  transform:rotate(10deg) scale(1.3);
  transition: 0.5s transform;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="demo" width="480" height="295" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu6TL.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can blur video posters with the following style:

```css
.blur {
    -webkit-filter: blur(125px);
    -moz-filter: blur(125px);
    -o-filter: blur(125px);
    -ms-filter: blur(125px);
    filter: blur(125px);
}
```

An example is visible [here](https://codepen.io/tyrus/pen/twpuK).